# Flixster dataset

Tags: data-request

Where can I find the Flixster dataset referenced by most social recommender system papers? Most of the papers reference this now-dead link ... http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~sja25/personal/datasets/ . Does anyone know where the data can now be located?

Comment: Ask https://www.linkedin.com/in/mohsenjamali/

Comment: The link does not work anymore. It needs permission. Could you please give us access to this dataset?

Answer (score 2):

Googling for 'Flixter dataset', the first hit I get is from Arizona State University on [this page](http://socialcomputing.asu.edu/datasets/Flixster).

> Flixster is a social movie site allowing users to share movie ratings, discover new movies and meet others with similar movie taste. This contains the friendship network crawled in December 2010 by Javier Parra (Javier.Parra@asu.edu). For easier understanding, all the contents are organized in CSV file format.
>
> Basic statistics
> Number of Nodes: 2,523,386
> Number of Edges: 9,197,338

The [download link](http://socialcomputing.asu.edu/uploads/1296675547/Flixster-dataset.zip) serves a 36 MB ZIP file.

Comment: Yes im done research and the file you attached is a friendship network dataset. But i need dataset with user rating and films that used in papers

Comment: **That should all be in your question**. You cannot assume that people understand you if all you write is *Flixster dataset referenced by most of social recommender system papers*. **What papers** (examples) and **what dataset** (description)?

Comment: the paper is " SVD-based incremental approaches for recommender systems " and the dataset contains films, users and users rating for this films

Answer (score 2):

You can access the original author's website here: https://sites.google.com/view/mohsenjamali/home